# .htaccess rewrite rule for url with matching directory name gives undesired results

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The .htaccess for my web app redirects all urls to a subdomain. The rules I'm using work in some cases but it does not work when the url has the same name as a directory name. I will simplify my problem with two cases.

The file structure is like this:

```
/app
|____ .htaccess
|____ /www
|  |____ .htaccess
|  |____ /articles
|  |  |____ frontpage.php
|  |  |____ article.php
```

The first .htaccess file (directly under /app) rewrites any url to point to the subdir www:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine on    

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} localhost [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/www 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} localhost [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /www/index.php [L]
```

The second .htaccess file (under www) has the following rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /www
RewriteRule ^articles/?$ /articles/frontpage.php [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^articles/([0-9+]*)/?$ /articles/article.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

**CASE 1:** If I browse to **/articles/** (with a trailing slash) then apache finds the page and renders it successfully.  I'm happy with this result.

**CASE 2:** If I browse to **/articles** (without a trailing slash) then apache redirects (appends??) the browser to **/www/articles/** (although it still renders the page correctly).  Unhappy.

What gives? For one, what is causing the redirect? For two, any clues as to how I can achieve what I'm looking for *without* having to rename all of my directories?

I tried adding some logic that would append a "/" if the REQUEST_URI is a directory but I couldn't get it to work and ideally i wouldn't even have to add a trailing slash ("/articles" would just work).

I should mention that browsing to **/articles/1** succeeds without appending the www and renders the page.

Answer (score 0):

I found something that works. I feel like it is not the cleanest solution but so far it's all I've come up with.  What I don't like about it is that it requires the Index to be index.php but in my case they are, so it works for me.

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine on    

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/www/%{REQUEST_URI} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/www/%{REQUEST_URI} -l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/$1/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} localhost [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/www 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} localhost [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /www/index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also replace the [L] with [END] if you are working on a high end apache server

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine on    

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/www/%{REQUEST_URI} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/www/%{REQUEST_URI} -l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/$1/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} localhost [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/www 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/$1 [END]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} localhost [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /www/index.php [END]
```